# How to iterate over Variadic template types (not arguments)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I am writing a class which expects variable number of template types. I need to call a subscriber for each type but note that there are no actual arguments passed to the class. Something like:

```
template<typename... T>
class Subscriber
{
    Subscriber()
    {
        // for(typename X: T)   <-- How to do this?
        // {
        //      PubSub.Subscribe<X>( [](auto data){ // do something with data} );
        // }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, in C++17, you might do:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class Subscriber
{
    Subscriber()
    {
        auto f = [](auto data){ /* do something with data*/ };
        (PubSub.Subscribe<Ts>(f), ...);
    }
}
```

In C++11/14, you might to use more verbose way, such as:

(C++14 currently with your generic lambda)

```
template<typename... Ts>
class Subscriber
{
    Subscriber()
    {
        auto f = [](auto data){ /* do something with data*/ };
        int dummy[] = {0, (PubSub.Subscribe<Ts>(f), void(), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is X, in your answer?

Comment: @NeilGatenby: a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Why do you add `void()` before `0`? To avoid pitfalls of `operator,`?

Comment: @Evg: Exactly. I should ideally also do that for C++17 version.

Comment: @Jarod42 can you please explain a bit how C++14 version works? or point me to the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: pack expansion is limited to several place including function parameter (`f(args...)`), initializer_list. The former doesn't ensure left to right order, the later does. initializer_list can be used to construct array, so `int dummy = {(f<Ts>(), 0)...};`. `(f<Ts>(), 0)` use comma to ensure return type is `int`. Then void() is to handle evil `operator,` overload, and extra `0,` is to handle empty pack.